# Падёж и склонение слов: палатке, сене, каше, охоте, заботы

Tags: склонение, падежи, существительные

Каковы падёж и склонение следующих слов?

1. палатке
2. сене
3. каше
4. охоте
5. заботы

Comment: Оформите вопрос грамотно. Запишите текст строчными буквами, запишите слова в составе    словосочетаний, в том числе предложных (только в этом случае можно определить  падеж). Также укажите ваши варианты ответов.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что Д/З

Answer (score -1):

Палатка, каша, охота, забота - 1-е склонение.

Сено - 2-е склонение.

Подглядываем тут: http://school-assistant.ru/?predmet=russian&theme=sklonenie_imen_sush и тут: http://beginnerschool.ru/gen_rules/gen_russ/tri-skloneniya-imen-sushhestvitelnyih

С падежами без контекста будет сложнее... Предлоги нужны, если нет контекста, иначе нужно будет говорить о каждом отдельно, все имеют право на жизнь.

В палатке, к палатке, о палатке, по палатке, на палатке...

**Падежи и предлоги**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Вот и примеряем все указанные предлоги.

В словах ПАЛАТКЕ, КАШЕ, ОХОТЕ, СЕНЕ это может быть как дательный, так и предложный падеж,

со словом ЗАБОТЫ проще: от заботы, без заботы, для заботы - только родительный (если, конечно, слово, подобно другим, дано в единственном числе).

Comment: "ПАЛАТКЕ", "КАШЕ" и "ОХОТЕ" может быть и **дательный**, если не исходить из предположения, что для всех слов должен быть один и тот же падеж.

Comment: Ага. Как-то упустила. 8-( Да нет же, не упустила, а не тот падеж указала, винительного там и быть не может. (((

Comment: Кстати, пересмотрите Ваше заключение про винительный, пожалуйста.

Comment: "ЗАБОТЫ" - может вполне быть множественное число.

Comment: Пожалуйста: Именительный, винительный.

Comment: Что "пожалуйста"?  ПАЛАТКЕ не "может быть как винительный, так и предложный" хотя бы только потому, что у слова "ПАЛАТКА" форма винительного падежа "ПАЛАТК**У**".

Comment: Но я же отвечаю на предшествующий коммент - о заботах во мн. ч.

Comment: Не надо отвечать.  Исправляйте свою белиберду в ответе.

Comment: Уже ушла чинить белиберду.

Comment: Господи, ну если вопрос белиберда, так зачем её множить-то? Да еще отвечать серьезно?!